# Removing extra quote character from CSV with regex

Tags: regex, csv

I have a large number of CSV files with double quotes as the entry delimiter, but some entries have the same character, as in below.

```
"MAIN 8" PIPE, PART B","Report 7"
```

I'm trying to just match the extra '"' character so that I can replace it with another character to read in the files.

I tried using the regex `([^","])"([^","])`. But it matched the characters `8"` and `7"`, where I would just like the `"` in the middle of `8"`.

I know I need to get it to check the endline character and not match the characters around the `"` that I am looking for. Any tips to do this are appreciated.

Comment: You should probably fix this problem at the source.  Double quotes which are not part of the escaped entire column should be escaped somehow.

Comment: what language ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
(?<!^|",)"(?!,"|$)
```

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QJFpmp/3)

OR

[`(?<!^)(?<!",)"+(?!,"|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/QJFpmp/5)

Replace each match with some other character, say `#`

**Explanation:(1st Regex)**

- `(?<!^|",)` - matches a position which is immediately neither preceded by start of the string nor by the sequence `",`
- `"` - matches `"` literally
- `(?!,"|$)` - matches a position which is **not** immediately followed by either end of the string or the sequence `,"`

Comment: But your look behind assertion is not fixed width ! It may not work everywhere, as we don't know the flavor yet

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman A workaround for that may be [`(?<!^)(?<!",)"(?!,"|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/QJFpmp/4)

Comment: Great, this works for my case. I agree with others that it's best to fix this at the source, but unfortunately my CSV files come from thousands of users so that's not a path I can take.

Answer (score 1):

The source of the problem should be fixed in my opinion. However you may try the following solution to find the double quote and replace them accordingly:

Search By:

```
(?<!,)(?<!^)\"+(?!\s*(?:,|$))
```

And Replace by anything you want

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/DPefGn/22)

The above will work but to make it more safe you should first do some replace operation , otherwise neither mine nor any other regex solution will work for the case like this:

```
"abac"c    "    ,  "   blaljak"sdf "
```

So what you need to do is remove any space the that sits before or after a double quote.

So apply this replace operations first:

```
\s*(\")\s*
```

and replace by this:

```
\1
```

then apply the original regex i provided.

Comment: Hi, It won't work for string like [`"hellow """kjskljdfkljdsf","23"`](https://regex101.com/r/DPefGn/18)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Notepad++, So I can use below regex in Replace window to do it:

Find What:

```
(^|,)([^"][^,]+?)"(?=,|$)
```

Replace with:

```
\1\2
```

Comment: "MAIN 8" PIPE, PART B","Report blab"la 7"