# Is there a regular expression that can remove double quotes inside a csv column?

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

In developing an SSIS package I am receiving a daily .csv from an entity that cannot change their formatting. I receive a .csv that has double quote " text qualifier. Occasionally the data I receive has an extra double quote at various locations in the column. For example:

```
"Simpson, Homer", "123456", "742 "E" Evergreen Terrace", "(555) 555-5555".
```

I need to remove the double quotes around the E in the 742 "E" Evergreen Terrace. I tried the following already but was unsuccessful:

```
Regex.Replace(line, "(?<!(,|^))\"(?!($|,))", x => x.Value.Replace("\"", ""))
```

Is there a regular expression that can accomplish this?

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48363978/removing-extra-quote-character-from-csv-with-regex

Comment: Ask the one who creates the CSV to create proper CSV. "Cannot change their formatting" is a bad excuse. offer them to assist in fixing the bug. Creating CSV is not as simple as concatenating some strings.

Comment: @ThomasWeller In the real world we often have to deal with CSV created by programs that "have always done it that way" and getting the vendor to change their broken code is next to impossible. I want to live in a world where things get done right, but sadly this is not that world.